# Manually entering <pre> tag in answer edit box yields script error in IE 7

Tags: bug, status-declined, edits, javascript, internet-explorer-7

It occurs to me that I don't know whether you intend to support IE 7. But anyway, since FF is giving me problems today for unknown reasons, I am using IE 7.

My code blocks were showing an extra unneeded CR at the end, so I decided to try using the `<code>` and `<pre>` tags I've occasionally seen used instead of indenting. When I typed the opening `<pre>` tag, I got a javascript error on every keystroke until the closing tag was in place. I tried debugging in VS 2008 to tell you the exact line, but it could not display the code. The error message was non-descript.

Try it to see what I mean. If you have trouble replicating it on a different answer, [here's the one I was editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333687/tsql-counting-how-many-occurrences-on-each-day/6333737#6333737).

Note: I have used Ctrl-F5 to attempt to reload any cached bad javascript, but it did not clear up the problem.

Update: I duplicated this problem on another IE7 machine, Ctrl-F5 did not clear it up. An IE8 machine did not have the problem. Firefox 4 does not have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 is only minimally supported, so this manual behavior resulting in an error is not something we'd spend a lot of engineering support on.